# Laravel 4 error in Netbeans for passing closure variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Netbeans, I get an error on the following syntax:

```
if($user){ 
    Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', array('link' => URL::route('account-activate'), 'username' => $username), function($message) use $user{
    $message->to($user->email, $user->username)->subject('activate your account'); 
    }); 
    return Helper_Response::success($user); 
}
```

The error is:

```
Unexpected variable $user
```

I can't see what's wrong. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: use ($user) brackets around variable

Comment: Wow, thanks dude, it was a mistake in the tutorial that he corrected a few minutes later :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use parenthesis on closure `use` clause:

```
$closure = function($message) use ($user) { 
   ...
};
```